# Keywords/skills feature similar to that of LinkedIn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design, autocomplete, database-schema

My web app will have users fill out an application for their profile. Users can enter their skills with years of experience on them. I might have a skills table in my database. A User has_many Skills and a Skill has_many Users.

When a skill has many users, wouldn't that make my table extremely huge because although a skill may already be created in the db, it would have to create a new row to match the user_id? If so, is there a more efficient way to do this (I imagine this format would be costly for the server)? Generally speaking, users could have a range of 0 skills up to 100's each.

The skills need to be cross referenced with a posting so that only users who meet x skills can see y posting. For example, the posting requires that user has x, y, z skills with the correlating lengths of experience. This would be a set of control structures. Say one user puts his skill is 'rails framework' and another user puts his skill is in 'rails development'. These are the same skills, but for the person making the post, to make sure they're getting all qualified users, they have to enter each format of the skill. Is there a way around this so it is more effective and efficient?

It might have a LinkedIn, StackOverflow, Quora styled format for skills where they start typing a skill and it autocompletes/creates suggestions and then the user just clicks the appropriate skill.

Comment: This question seems broad for StackOverflow - [Choosing between Stack Overflow and Programmers Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254570/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange)

Comment: Please ask just one question per... um, question.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, what you're looking for is either a `has_and_belongs_to_many` or `has_many :through` association:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Essentially, you have a table of users, a table of skills, and a third table which serves to join particular users with particular skills.

The 2nd part of your question is a complicated one. By allowing users free reign over entering the skills into your system you lose some control. This is something StackOverflow also has to deal with. Here it is addressed with moderators and community edits, which earn the individuals helping out credits within SO.

Depending on the sort of system you're building, you'll either need paid moderators to provide tight control over how everything is working, or open it up to the community so that they can get it to work the way they want it to. Both of these have their pros and cons, but without keeping complete control over the skills list you can't get away from the issue of duplicate or very similar skills which ought to be the same thing.